# How to pass controller data to view in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'd like to know how to pass my controller data to the view using Laravel.
This my Controller:

```
     $ourput =   DB::table('database')
                    ->leftjoin('table', 'database.id', '=', 'table.id')
                  //  ->leftjoin('table', 'table.type_id', '=', 'table.type.id')
                    ->where('database.id', '=', $sess_id )
                     -


                     ->get();
             if($Data){
                return redirect('view')->with('key', $value); 
            }else{
                return FALSE;
            }

        }
```

Comment: i  am print {{$driverprofiles}} like this but i am  getting error undefined driverprofiles so how to display data

Comment: any one please give me a suggection

Comment: Try return redirect()->route('driverprofile')->with(['driverprofiles'  =>  $driverData]);  or redirect()->url('driverprofile')->with(['driverprofiles'  =>  $driverData]);

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be trying to return a view, not a HTTP redirect response. In which case instead of this:

```php
return redirect('driverprofile')->with('driverprofiles', $driverData);
```

it should read something like this

```php
return view('driverprofile')->with('driverprofiles', $driverData);
```